# Page Attributes Panel (Parent option) is not showing on a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

i have this when registrating my cpt:

```
'supports' => ['title', 'editor','thumbnail', 'page-attriutes'],
'hierarchical' => true, // Allows your posts to behave like Hierarchy Pages
```

However, the 'page-attributes' panel with the Parent Option is not displaying.  What am I missing?  How can I enable the parent option for the cpt?

Comment: Your `supports` array is using `page-attriutes`, so you're probably just missing a `b` there... Or was that just a typo in the question body?

Comment: OMG. That's quiet emberassing :s Sometimes it is so obvious that you don't see it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misspelt `attributes` and used `page-attriutes` which doesn't exist,

Instead add `page-attributes`

Comment: OMG. That's quiet emberassing :s Sometimes it is so obvious that you don't see it. Thank you.